# React-Native (0.64.2) Formik handleSubmit onSubmit not firing

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, formik, yup

**Relevant Modules**:

**Formik**: "2.1.4"

**Yup**: "0.28.5"

**React-Navigation** v5

So i've been struggling with a simple formik problem for a day now, and I'm sure I must be missing something, but I would love some help, because I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I have two files: `Login/index.tsx` & `Login/LoginForm.tsx`

**Login/index.tsx** for the most part looks like this:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    console.log("values submitted == ", values)
  }

  return (
    <View style={Styles.container}>
      <CircleIconButton
        size={60}
        backgroundColor={'white'} 
        onPress={goBack}
      >
        <Icon name={'arrow-left'} type={'FontAwesome5'} style={{ color: Colors.primaryOrange}} />
      </CircleIconButton>

      <Text style={[Typography.title, {color: 'white', marginTop: '30%'}]}>
        Login
      </Text>
      <Text style={[Typography.titleDesc, {color: 'white', marginTop: '3%', marginBottom: '8%'}]}>
        Securely login to your account
      </Text>

      <Formik
        initialValues={formInitialValues}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <LoginForm />
      </Formik>
      
    </View>
  )
```

**Login/LoginForm.tsx** for the most part looks like this:

```
const {handleChange, handleSubmit, values, isSubmitting, isValidating} = useFormikContext();

const { navigate } = useNavigation()

return (
    <View style={Styles.container}>
      <IVTextInput
        onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
        value={values?.email}
        editable
        fieldLabel={"Phone/Email"}
      />
      <IVTextInput
        isPassword
        editable
        containerStyle={{ marginTop: '8%', marginBottom: '15%' }}
        onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
        value={values?.password}
        fieldLabel={"Your Password"}
      />
      <RoundedButton
        block
        onPress={handleSubmit}
      >
        Log In
      </RoundedButton>
      <View style={{...allCenter, marginTop: '7%'}}>
        <Text
          style={[Typography.titleDesc, Styles.signupTextButton]}
          onPress={() => navigate('Signup')}
        >
          Don’t have an account? Register
        </Text>

        <Text style={[Typography.titleDesc, {color: 'white', marginTop: '8%'}]}>
          Forgot Password
        </Text>

      </View>
    </View>
  )
```

LoginForm is wrapped by the `<Formik>` tags. I then try to access the formik context in the LoginForm.tsx file.

Things i've tried:

- Printing the `values` variables as it changes (from me typing in the textfields), and **I can see that the values object is tracking my keystrokes**
- Printing `isSubmitting` & `isValidating`, and at no point has `isSubmitting` = true AND `isValidating` = false. when I submit `isSubmitting` == **true** and `isValidating` == **true**. The docs for Formik seem to suggest that I know when my form is submitting when `isValidating` == false && `isSubmitting` == **true** but that hasn't happened yet.
- Creating a Yup schema, but i've also tried removing the yup schema within the `<Formik>` tag inside the **Login/index.tsx** file, either way, neither the `onSubmit` nor the `handleSubmit` funciton do anything when I tap the **Login button**.
- Put in a simple `console.log()` statement to test that the action to my `<RoundedButton>` `onPress` prop is working, and it worked, my `console.log()` was seen in the console output.
- Returning an empty object from the **validate** prop within the `<Formik>` opening tag, because the general consensus I get from looking online is that the form doesn't submit when the validation fails

**Interesting Info**: When I used a validationSchema, I purposely violated the validation, and when I printed errors the object was empty

> The gist is . . . nothing i've tried seems to get the onSubmit or
> handleSubmit functions to fire. Please let me know what I could be
> doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I just realised that my onSubmit event wasn't firing because it doesn't fire at all unless the form is valid and I kept clicking submit on an invalid form. So if you have an invalid field you'll never see it submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a validationScheme the handleSubmit would not be triggered until the validations on the inputs are fulfilled.